# Retrieve a variable content and make it a string with Jquery

Tags: jquery, variables, url

I need to retrieve a Url to add as meta data using JQuery. I have an image with a SRC. I need to get that value and pass it to a meta data function. Basically, I need the `data-a2a-url` variable to be filled with my url value.

`imgShared` is the variable with the URL to retrieve
I did this:

```
class="lb-image" src="http://wwww.mysite/xxxx.jpg">

var imgShared = $(".lb-image").attr("src", $(this));

$('<div data-a2a-url="imgShared" data-a2a-title="here the title" ').appendTo("  here another div  "); 

});
```

Unfortunately it does not work.

Any idea is welcome!

Answer (score 0):

**To get the value** of an attribute you need to use

```
var imgShared = $(".lb-image").attr("src");
```

And **to set the value** you should use

```
var imgShared = $(".lb-image").attr("src", VALUE);
```

Hope this answers your question.

**UPDATE:**

Check out the with dynamic URL and Image sharing example [**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/pratik_shah/pen/GJyvBG?editors=101)..

I am not able to share code here as Any2Share need cookies and stackCodeEditor doesn't allow cookies..

Comment: Hi. Thanks. I tried but again, it does not retrieve the url and pass to metadata data-a2a-url="imgShared". that is the issue...when i share,it will display always *imgShared content and not the value of the URL. my issue is to convert that name of the variable in the content (http=...ec..etc.).

Comment: I think the issue is in  data-a2a-url="imgShared" . i do not think i did it correctly

Comment: Hi Pratik. The issue not disappear is using as attribute SRC. the url is not printed on the screen and the share does not work. did i do wrong maybe_? 
var imgShared = $(".lb-image").text(attr("src"));  data-a2a-url="'+ imgShared +'"

Comment: Can you give us your exact scenario or what are you trying to do? your code's jsFiddle will work..

Comment: I am trying to retrieve the URL of any image in my photo gallery *(my website) and sharing with add to any. I am using metadata and if i set a complete url in html is shared. But of c ourse i need to do dinamically using jquery... at the moment i am only able to share the page not the single image in lightbox.. see here http://www.paolobergomi.it/new-gallery/night/

Comment: var imgShared = $(".lb-image").attr("src");
this has to become a url . and passed to  data-a2a-url that is all...

Comment: Hi @PaoloBergomi Check out the live sharing example in my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var imgShared = $(".lb-image").attr("src");

$('<div data-a2a-url="' + imgShared + '" data-a2a-title="here the title"></div>').appendTo('#another-div');
```

Comment: I tried but it does not display the right url. not sure why..investigating